# NSString is exactly the same as CFString?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

O'Reilly's Programming iOS 5 says (maybe in a looser sense), that "an NSString is a CFString".  But is it true that at least `NSString *` will point to some memory chunk with an `isa`, while `CFStringRef` probably does not?

Comment: I got dain bramaged on this page I can't right!

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly the same; they are *Toll-Free Bridged*.  This [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) should explain in more detail.

Here is even more detail from *iOS 5 Programming Pushing The Limits* on [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LFaxcuKxVf0C&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=toll-free%20bridged%20isa&source=bl&ots=Nf1qGSdee8&sig=z8ceZCJCjyBVAh72hkzjB2m9niE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eqplUPP4LInG0QWLv4DYDw&ved=0CHUQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=toll-free%20bridged%20isa&f=false).

Comment: And for even *more* detail, and an entertaining read, see ridiculous fish's excellent writeup: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/bridge.html

Comment: so `CFStringRef` is a C pointer (it is `void *`), but the structure also has an `isa`, but it points to NSCFString, while NSString has almost the same content, except its `isa` points to NSString, otherwise, all the other bytes are the same in an NSString object and a CFString struct?  (so toll free bridging changes the `isa` only)

Comment: @動靜能量 There is also a 4-byte `cfinfo` element with a Core Foundation object.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks.  how can the cast change the `isa` and use it as NSString if there are 4 extra bytes?

Comment: @動靜能量 As the Google book link explains, a check is made of the type stored in the (cf)isa element, and the appropriate implementation is called.

Comment: if I cast from NSString @"hello" to CFString using `cfs = (__bridge CFStringRef) s`, the resulting variable, when printed out using "%p", it has the same address as the NSString object... and if I use a `char *` to print the 15 bytes pointed to by `s`, and then do the cast, and print out the 15 bytes, they are the exact same 15 bytes.  I thought the `isa` should be different as they point to different classes?

Comment: @動靜能量 Casting won't change the address of any object.  However you should be able to call `CFString...` functions and `NSString` methods on that `NSString` and they should all work.

Comment: You can see how it works on the CF side in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/CFString.c

Comment: @動靜能量 They do not point to different classes. `cfs` and `s` both contain the same pointer to the same object, and that object's `isa` pointer does not change when you cast the object's pointer, nor at any other time related to accessing the object via one variable or the other.